# npm install errors out on all packes if npm-shrinkwrap.json is present

Tags: npm-install, npm-shrinkwrap

node v10.15.0
    npm  v6.4.1

I inherited a project that has an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` next to the `package.json`.

When I run `npm install` I get errors like the following for the files in every single package that should be downloaded

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\node_modules\.staging\core-js-12a70f6a\fn\number\virtual\index.js'
```

Checking the .staging folder I see that the files are actually there!

Out of curiosity I removed the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and run `npm install` again and now it creates the node_modules folders as expected.

I found that `shrinkwrap` is an old method, replaced by the `lock` mechanism in later NPM versions?

Would it be save to just delete the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` and not run into any issues with package versions later?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Jens Hi, did you find a solution to this?